# MongoDB / Motor - How can I query the availability of transaction support?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, motor-asyncio

I am trying to determine if I can use transactions in a MongoDB server.

What I tried:

- I am querying `replSetGetStatus` with admin command, if `set` is inside the `replSetStatus`, I set `is_replica` to True. If admin command is not usable, pass.
- Query `listDatabases` with admin command, if any of the database name is `config` and database name consists `partitioned`, set `is_sharded` to True. If admin command is not usable, pass.
- If `is_replica` or `is_sharded` is `True`, then we can use transaction. Return True.
- If neither of them are false, fallback to, in my own words, oonga boonga method.
- Start a database session, and try to start transaction, then commit the transaction.
- If no errors, return True. For everything else, return False.

Above all of this, my function STILL returns incorrectly. I am getting

```
OperationFailure: Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos, full error: {'ok': 0.0, 'errmsg': 'Transaction numbers are only allowed on a replica set member or mongos', 'code': 20, 'codeName': 'IllegalOperation'}
```

error when I rely on this functions result.

Full code:

```py
    async def __supports_tx(self) -> bool:
        try:
            is_sharded = False
            is_replica = False
            # Check if the deployment is a replica set
            try:
                repl_set_status = await self.client.admin.command(
                    {"replSetGetStatus": 1}
                )
                if "set" in repl_set_status:
                    is_replica = True
            except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
                pass

            # Check if the deployment is a sharded cluster using listDatabases
            try:
                databases_info = await self.client.admin.command({"listDatabases": 1})
                for db in databases_info["databases"]:
                    if db["name"] == "config" and "partitioned" in db:
                        # 'partitioned' key exists in 'config' database of sharded cluster
                        is_sharded = True
            except pymongo.errors.PyMongoError:
                pass

            if is_replica or is_sharded:
                return True  # Transactions are supported for replica set or sharded cluster

            # If neither replica set nor sharded cluster, attempt to start a transaction to check for support
            async with await self.client.start_session() as session:
                try:
                    session.start_transaction()
                    await session.commit_transaction()
                    return True  # Transactions are supported
                except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure as exc:
                    if ("Transaction numbers are only allowed" in str(exc)) or (
                        exc.code == 20
                    ):
                        return False  # Transactions are not supported
                    else:
                        raise  # Re-raise the exception if it's not related to transaction support
        except pymongo.errors.OperationFailure:
            return False  # Any other errors, consider transactions not supported
```

What can I do?